# WP query returning limited items only from two childs

Tags: wordpress

I am using code as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'portfolio',
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'studio-blu',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'include_children' => true,
        ),
    ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if($the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');
        ?>
        <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 <?php the_category(' '); ?>">
            <a class="magnific-popup" href="<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>" />
            </a>
            
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Here, `studio-blu` is the parent category of the custom post type. It has 0 posts directly, however, it has the following children with the corresponding number of posts.

```
ads      = 9
branding = 1
events   = 4
logos    = 7
misc     = 4
```

However, on the above wp_query, it is returning only 10 items, i.e, 9 from ads and 1 from branding. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found the problem, the issue was I was missing `'posts_per_page' => -1,` under $args. Now, my `$args` looks like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'portfolio',
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'studio-blu',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'include_children' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
```